# openstack heat doesn't recognize key_name parameter : using existing & newly created keypair

Tags: openstack

I was trying to create a `stack` in **Openstack**. But I am getting the following error in two cases:

(1) using the already existing key in `OpenStack`.
(2) Using newly created key pair. Please assist me.

```
Property error: resources.server.properties.key_name: Error validating value 'CBAMnew195.pem': The Key (CBAMnew195.pem) could not be found.
2021-03-31 13:02:19Z [cbam5gvinni195]: CREATE_FAILED  Resource CREATE failed: resources[0]: resources.single.resources.heal_group.Property error: resources.server.properties.key_name: Error validating value 'CBAMnew195.pem': The Key (CBAMnew195.pem) could not be found.
```

**Error snip**

[image: 1]

Comment: What if you try the ID of the key instead of the name?

Comment: Can you add the template that causes these errors, or the relevant parts, to the question? Please don't take screenshots but paste text. Don't forget to format it as code.